# Getting a count of objects that span a relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get a count of objects that span a relation. Every TestPlan contains n cases. The method plan_case_count() gives me the count. Every TestPlanCase contains n steps. I want to get the total of all steps for all cases associated with the plan. The method plan_case_step_count() is supposed to do that by iterating through the queryset and adding up the counts. But it doesn't work. The error message I get is:

*'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'testplanstep_set'*

```
class TestPlan(models.Model):
    tp_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tp_version = models.IntegerField()
    tp_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def plan_case_count(self):
        """This one works"""
        return self.testplancase_set.count()

    def plan_case_step_count(self):
        """This one doesn't"""
        pcs_count = 0
        for case in self.testplancase_set:
            pcs_count += case.testplanstep_set.count()
        return pcs_count


class TestPlanCase(models.Model):
    tpc_plan = models.ForeignKey(TestPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tpc_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tpc_seq_no = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class TestPlanStep(models.Model):
    tps_case =  models.ForeignKey(TestPlanCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tps_step = models.ForeignKey(TestSteps, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tps_ok =  models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=Choices.yes_no)
    tps_issue = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write the count query directly:

```
def plan_case_step_count(self):
    return TestPlanStep.objects.filter(tps_case__tpc_plan=self).count()
```

This will write a `COUNT(*)` query in SQL directly with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Magic! You're the man! ;) Has to be:
return TestPlanStep.objects.filter(tps_case__tpc_plan=self).count()
though.

Comment: @uwain12345: aarggh, yes, I forgot the manager, thanks, updated.